# sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected when using backticks perl

Tags: bash, perl, backticks

```
my $mysql_cmd = 'debconf-set-selections <<< \'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password 6ygr\' ;debconf-set-selections <<< \'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password 6ygr\'; '.our $install_cmd." mysql-server";
my $mysql_stat = `$mysql_cmd`;
```

I'm using the above piece of code to install mysql from my perl script. But I'm getting this error

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

When I printed `$mysql_cmd` I got `debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password 6ygr' ;debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password 6ygr'; apt-get -y install  mysql-server`

which seems to correct and manually executing this command in shell gives desired output. But when execute the perl script it gives error. Any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use [`IPC::Run`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) for this kind of jobs

```
use IPC::Run qw(run);
my @options = map "mysql-server mysql-server/$_ password 6ygr",
    qw(root_password root_password_again);
my $mysql_stat;
run [qw(debconf-set-selections)], '<', \$_, '>>', \$mysql_stat, '2>>', \$mysql_stat
    or die "debconf-set-selections: $?"
    for @options;
run [ $install_cmd, 'mysql-server' ], '>>', \$mysql_stat, '2>>', \$mysql_stat
    or die "$install_cmd: $?";
```

The main reason is you don't like to deal with quoting issues and incompatibilities and so on.

Comment: That's a ridiculously inelegant solution to a simple problem. Ouch.

Comment: @tpartee: I would expect someone with your experience will appreciate robustness and safeness of the solution. What a shame.

Answer (score 7):

perl uses `/bin/sh` to execute commands. Try feeding that string to sh and if you get the same error that is the problem.

If you want to use bash to execute that statement, use `bash -c "cmd args ..."` as the command.

If you only need to pass a single line to a command, it may be a good idea to avoid the non-portable bashism of `<<<`. Instead, use `echo "whatever" | command` which works in any shell.